# Add span inside a button when using append()

Tags: javascript, jquery

I use append() when creating buttons. How do I have a < span > within the append text?

Basically I want to do this

```
<button type="button" class="btn btn-default" id="test1" >
     <span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></span>
</button>
```

here

```
$( '<button />' , { class: 'btn btn-default', type: 'button', id: 'test1' })
```

Comment: put class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left" in button 'value' attribute

Answer (score 2, accepted):

You can use the html attribute as well like this

```
$('<button />', {
  class: 'btn btn-default',
  type: 'button',
  id: 'test1',
  html: '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></span>'
});
```

[Here is a reference](http://api.jquery.com/jQuery/#jQuery-html-attributes)

```js
var b = $( '<button />' , { class: 'btn btn-default', type: 'button', id: 'test1', html: '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></span>' });
$('body').append(b);
```

```html
<script src="https://ajax.googleapis.com/ajax/libs/jquery/2.1.1/jquery.min.js"></script>
```

Answer (score 0):

You may use html:

```
    $( '<button />' , { 'class': 'btn btn-default', type: 'button', id: 'test1',
         html: '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></span>' })
```

Notice: class is a reserved word. So use it inside the quote.

Answer (score 0):

How about this :

```
$( '<button />' , { 
     class   : 'btn btn-default', 
     type    : 'button', 
     id      : 'test1', 
     html    : '<span class="glyphicon glyphicon-arrow-left"></span>' 
})
```

Comment: @Fergoso Thanks for mentioning, should be html.